# How to show Android Studio IDE colors on Windows 10

Tags: windows, android-studio, colors, ide

I just installed Android studio on my windows 10, but the ide doesn't show the code colors, it looks like this:

[image]

So i want to know how can i show the ide colors.

Answer (score 0):

**This happens because you haven't installed the plugins that you need.  Try following steps**

1. Open Android Studio Settings ( `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `S`).
2. Plugins
3. Install **Dart** & **Flutter** Plugings and click apply.
4. Restart the Android Studio.

Hope You helpful!

Comment: I reinstalled it and now it's working. Dunno how true is your answer, but thanks a lot anyway for the help

Comment: You are welcome & happy coding!